# Delegating to properties in C#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, properties

I'm doing something with an Odbc DataReader.  Each row in a query result should be transformed into a `ResultObject` looking like this:

```
struct ResultObject {
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In order to write more domain-specific code, I want to transform this code

```
var query = "SELECT Prop1, Prop2, ... FROM MyTable;";
... connect, submit query
while( reader.Read() ) {
  var fieldValue = fields[ fieldindex ];
  switch( fieldindex ) {
     case( indexProp1 ): result.Prop1.Set( (int) fieldValue); break;
     case( indexProp2 ): result.Prop2.Set( (string) fieldvalue); break;
     ...
  }
}
```

into something more generic, where I build the mapping between indices and 'setters' dynamically:

But it would be nice to have something even more concise like:

```
PropMapper mappers[] = {
 new PropMapper("Prop1", ResultType.Prop1 ),
 new PropMapper("Prop2", ResultType.Prop2 ),
 ....
};
```

I have, however, no clue how to create a `PropMapper` from the property of a `ResultType`.

The question:

**How can I generate an object that wraps/delegates to a property of a given type?**

Note: though ORMs are quite useful for this, I'm really only asking how C# allows for creating the delegate (or anything equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

PropMapper would need to receive a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) as parameter, representing the property. Prism's [NotificationObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406218%28v=PandP.39%29.aspx) receives such an expression on its RaisePropertyChanged event.

You can take a look on [Prism's source code](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52595#1024364) how the lambda expression is used to extract the property and use it.

Comment: This way works the best with refactoring.  From the lambda, the property name, getter, and setter can all be determined.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Reflection:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = new PropertyInfo[]
{
  typeof(ResultObject).GetProperty("prop1"),
  typeof(ResultObject).GetProperty("prop2"),
};

for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
{
  props[i].SetValue(result, fieldValue, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look into a mini-orm like [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)